# angular 4 routing adding a component rather than replacing it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have configured routes as follows in a sub module loaded dynamically.
I don't think the dynamic loading is causing the problem, but it may - so I have included it for reference.

#### dynamic load

```
children: [
    {
        path: "dashboard",
        loadChildren: () => new Promise(resolve => {
            (require as any).ensure([],
                require => {
                    resolve(require("./dashboard/dashboard.module").DashboardModule);
                },
                "dashboard");
        })
    },
```

#### dashboard-routing-module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ClearingDashboardComponent,
        data: {
            title: "Dashboard"
        }
    },
    {
        path: "logs",
        component: LogDisplayComponent,
        data: {
            title: "Logs"
        }
    }
];
```

the landing HTML looks as follows

[image: dashboard component in red]

When navigating to the `LogDisplayComponent` with

```
const ne: NavigationExtras = {
    queryParams: { ... }
};
this.router.navigate(["dashboard/logs"], ne);
```

A new component is being added above the HTML.
Surely each component should replace the inner HTML?

[image]

The `LogDisplayComponent` is above the `ClearingDashboardComponent`, 
As I click, a new component is added each time I navigate either way?

*How do I fix the route to replace the component rather than add a new one?*

I am using angular 4.4.4...

Comment: You can simply destroy your component when you leave the routing (or when changing navigation event is fired). You have to create a dom reference `#yourReference` and simply add `this.yourReference.nativeElement.destroy()`

Comment: @LucaTaccagni, that's not the proper way of doing it. Angular manages component destruction and construction.

Comment: Check if this helps: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17261

Comment: I'll wait for someone to post an answer indicating how I should re-arrange the application appropriately. I would also have expected angular to create / remove the components.

Comment: @akash, it could be related, but my problem is not only a memory issue, the components are part of the DOM and being displayed as well.

Comment: @akash, I think you had it. I have updated to version 5.1.1 and the problem seems to have gone. Perhaps you should post that as the answer for other's benefit. Upgrade to a version without the bug?

Comment: @Jim, I've added the answer. Please accept it. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your version to 5+. This issue has already been addressed by the Angular team. For more information, check these links:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17261

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13725